# Matcher.group y error IllegalStateException

Tags: java, regex

Gracias por el foro y de antemano por la lectura. Estoy tratando de usar Matcher.group en Java pero me arroja un error **IllegalStateException**

El código de prueba que he generado es el siguiente. Sé que debería comprobar el método group() con un find() para previamente hacer la comprobación, pero no lo he hecho porque el patrón coincide. De hecho atrapo en la excepción el resultado del método find. Aun así, sigue lanzando la excepción y desconozco por qué.

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    final String regex = "([SA])([TPM])([0-9]{4})([AZ])";
    final Pattern patron = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher busqueda = patron.matcher("SP1234A");
    
    try {
        
        System.out.println(busqueda.group(1));
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("Error " + e.toString());
        System.out.println("Patrón: " + patron.toString() + " Búsqueda: " + busqueda.find());
    }

}
```

}

La salida en consola es la siguiente:

*Error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
Patrón: ([SA])([TPM])([0-9]{4})([AZ]) Búsqueda: true*

No sé por dónde agarrarlo. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que no estás usando el matcher apropiadamente.

Primero debes de usar tu matcher antes de obtener los detalles de comparación de la búsqueda. Si no tienes búsqueda no puedes hacer una comparación como puedes ver en [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) del método find

Si la comparación es exitosa, entonces se puede obtener más información mediante los métodos start, end, y group.

lo normal es ver un código similar al siguiente:

```
 while(busqueda.find()) {
        System.out.println("coincide: " + busqueda.group(1));
 }
```